# Angular Universal: Cache external HTTP calls across clients

Tags: angular, caching, angular-universal

I'm working on an Angular web app that uses Angular Universal, and that has several external API calls on every page.

I'm trying to implement an SSR cache for those API calls that works across clients, that is: when the app is rendered by **Client1** and that generates an HTTP call to **Endpoint1** from the Angular Universal server, the response is stored and returned when **Client2** has AU rendering a page that also calls **Endpoint1**.

Unfortunately I'm at a loss about how to proceed, as my understanding is that HTTP interceptors wouldn't work here as they won't store data across different clients. Something should probably be implemented at Express level in `server.ts`, but I don't know what exactly.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? 
I looked at caching the API but that might not be a good choice..

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same issue for an angular-universal project where certain pages contained data fetched from another api and the data was same for all clients. But each time i had to fetch them. Didn't find any valid solutions in angular side. So i implemented a mechanism at my express server.

Firstly i know which pages carry such data that can be cached. So i wrote a function that checks the url of the page for which client has requested and if it has any http call, the express server makes the call and gets the data. Then i used node-cache to cache the data on the express-server and putted a check before the http call so when another client requests for the same page the data is already in the cache. So now i can serve that data from cache. Next i sent the data to my angular component from my server.ts using providers, thus angular can now access the data.

**Server.ts**

```
server.get('*', async (req, res) => {
    var list = await getList(req.url);
    res.render(indexHtml, {
      req,
      providers: [
        {provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: req.baseUrl},
        {provide: 'REQUEST', useValue: req},
        {provide: 'RESPONSE', useValue: res},
        {provide: 'List', useValue: list},
      ],
    });
  });
```

The **getList** Function is

```
getList(url: string){
  if (/*checking for appropriate url*/) {

     var val = // check cache for data;
     if (val) {
        return val;
     }
     let response = // http call as no cache data
     if (response) {
        //save data to cache for further   
     }
     return response.data;
  }
  return null
}
```

And finally on the **angular component**

```
constructor(
    @Optional() @Inject('List') private list: any,
    ) {
  }
```

So now i can use it with `this.list`. This may not be the best approach . But it worked on my case.

Comment: For something like this I would implement the `npm i cache-manager` package. It will allow you to either use memory, or a shared caching resource such as memcached or redis.